# Buscar entres fechas JDateChoser java mysql

Tags: java, mysql

Me sale el siguiente error:

> you have an error in your sql syntax check the manual that corresponds
>   to your mariadb server version for right syntax to use near INNER JOIN
>   medicamento ON detalle_compra.idMedicamento = medicamento.idMedicament
>   at line 1

Lo siguiente es lo que tengo:

Función `mostrarCompras` de la clase:

```
 public DefaultTableModel mostrarCompras(String p_fecha_Desde, String p_fecha_Hasta) {

    DefaultTableModel modelo;

    String[] titulos = {"Codigo", "Nombre", "Categoria", "Cantidad", "Total", "Total F"};
    String[] registro = new String[6];

    totalRegistro = 0;
    modelo = new DefaultTableModel(null, titulos);

    String sSQL = "SELECT medicamento.codigo, medicamento.nombreMed, categoria.nombre, detalle_compra.cantidad, detalle_compra.totalFinal, compra.totalC"
            + "FROM detalle_compra INNER JOIN medicamento ON detalle_compra.idMedicamento = medicamento.idMedicamento"
            + "INNER JOIN compra ON detalle_compra.idCompra = compra.idCompra INNER JOIN categoria ON medicamento.idcategoria = categoria.idCategoria"
            + "WHERE compra.fechaCompra BETWEEN '%" + p_fecha_Desde + "%' AND '%" + p_fecha_Hasta + "%'";
    try {

        Statement st = cn.createStatement();

        try (ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sSQL)) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                registro[0] = rs.getString("codigo");
                registro[1] = rs.getString("nombreMed");
                registro[2] = rs.getString("nombre");
                registro[3] = rs.getString("cantidad");
                registro[4] = rs.getString("totalFinal");
                registro[5] = rs.getString("totalC");

                totalRegistro = totalRegistro + 1;
                modelo.addRow(registro);
            }
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e, "Advertencia", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, icono);
        return null;
    }
    return modelo;
}
```

Botón buscar:

```
private void btnBuscar1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    java.util.Date desde = new java.util.Date();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf_desde = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    desde = frmComprasDetalladas.dateDesde.getDate();
    String p_fecha_Desde = sdf_desde.format(desde);

    java.util.Date hasta = new java.util.Date();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf_hasta = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    hasta = frmComprasDetalladas.dateHasta.getDate();
    String p_fecha_Hasta = sdf_hasta.format(hasta);

    func.mostrarCompras(p_fecha_Desde, p_fecha_Hasta);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que los valores de las variables se rellenan correctamente, es posible que te falten espacios en la sentencia y por eso quede malformada, prueba así:

```
String sSQL = "SELECT medicamento.codigo, medicamento.nombreMed, categoria.nombre, detalle_compra.cantidad, detalle_compra.totalFinal, compra.totalC"
                + " FROM detalle_compra INNER JOIN medicamento ON detalle_compra.idMedicamento = medicamento.idMedicamento"
                + " INNER JOIN compra ON detalle_compra.idCompra = compra.idCompra INNER JOIN categoria ON medicamento.idcategoria = categoria.idCategoria"
                + " WHERE compra.fechaCompra BETWEEN '%" + p_fecha_Desde + "%' AND '%" + p_fecha_Hasta + "%' ";
```

En estos casos puedes imprimir la variable sSQL por ejemplo por consola y comprobar que la sentencia funciona en la base de datos.

Comment: gracias por sus respuestas he probado con las dos soluciones que me dan y no me busca

Comment: Las fechas que escogo de los jdatechoser las estoy enviendo bien?

Comment: Te sigue dando el mismo error en el mismo sitio? En teoría el formato de la fecha es el adecuado si los campos de la tabla son tipo date.

Comment: no, no no me da ningun error solo que al seleccionar el rango de fechas no me muestra nada., Si ejecuto la sentencia hasta antes del where me muestra los registros que tengo guardados en la bd pero si la ejecuto con el where no me muesta los registro y no me busca

Answer (score 1):

Veo tres problemas en el código:

1. Los espacios que faltan al final (o al principio) de cada parte de la consulta (se recomienda usar `append` en vez de `+` para unir cadenas).
2. `%` no se usa con `BETWEEN`, pues no funciona como un `LIKE`.
3. Riesgo de Inyección SQL.

Me permito abundar sobre el tercer problema por ser el más serio de todos y al final aporto una solución a los tres problemas.

[La documentación recomienda usar consultas preparadas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) cuando manejas datos que pueden venir desde el exterior, para evitar de ese modo la Inyección SQL.

Si por ejemplo el valor de `p_fecha_Desde` o de `p_fecha_Hasta` son recogidos en un formulario y pasas la consulta como lo estás haciendo ahora podrías tener inyección:

- Si en `p_fecha_Desde` el usuario mal intencionado escribe: `2017-07-01 AND 2017-07-20'; ALTER TABLE detalle_compra; ALTER TABLE medicamento; --`  La consulta pasada así **borraría las tablas `detalle_compra` y `medicamento`.**
- O si en `p_fecha_Hasta` el usuario mal intencionado escribe: `2017-07-20'; ALTER TABLE detalle_compra; ALTER TABLE medicamento; UPDATE usuarios SET password='adminhackeado' WHERE usuario='admin' --` No solamente se borrarían las tablas anteriores, sino que el usuario mal intencionado **cambiaría la clave del usuario `admin`** si el mismo exisitiese.
- Cosas peores podrían pasar si te inyectan código, como enviar desde SQL instrucciones a la línea de comandos.

De eso modo, cualquier tipo de consulta a la BD es posible, ya que tienes una puerta ancha y abierta para que entren en tu sistema.

Para prevenir eso, usa consultas preparadas, las cuales además te ayudan al momento de enviar correctamente los datos según su tipo.

Veamos una solución a los tres problemas:

```
String sSQL = "SELECT medicamento.codigo, medicamento.nombreMed, categoria.nombre, detalle_compra.cantidad, detalle_compra.totalFinal, compra.totalC"
            + " FROM detalle_compra INNER JOIN medicamento ON detalle_compra.idMedicamento = medicamento.idMedicamento"
            + " INNER JOIN compra ON detalle_compra.idCompra = compra.idCompra INNER JOIN categoria ON medicamento.idcategoria = categoria.idCategoria"
            + " WHERE compra.fechaCompra BETWEEN ? AND ?";
    try {

        PreparedStatement ps = cn.prepareStatement(sSQL);
        ps.setDate(1, java.sql.Date.valueOf(p_fecha_Desde));
        ps.setDate(2, java.sql.Date.valueOf(p_fecha_Hasta));

        try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(sSQL)) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                registro[0] = rs.getString("codigo");
                registro[1] = rs.getString("nombreMed");
                registro[2] = rs.getString("nombre");
                registro[3] = rs.getString("cantidad");
                registro[4] = rs.getString("totalFinal");
                registro[5] = rs.getString("totalC");

                totalRegistro = totalRegistro + 1;
                modelo.addRow(registro);
            }
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e, "Advertencia", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, icono);
        return null;
    }
    return modelo;
}
```